# Android SMS Verification message with prefix and hash string

Tags: android, sms

I am implementing a function about SMS verification automatically in my android app by using SMS Retriever. It is able to get message without asking READ_SMS permission. Here is the website [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview). After testing, if my app tries to receive the message, the message should look like this as mentioned from the website.

`<#> Your ExampleApp code is: 123ABC78
FA+9qCX9VSu`

It is working. But here is the question, the SMS message must include prefix and hash string. It will look really strange if users see this and feel confused. Is any possible way to get rid of these words show in phone message and my app is still able to receive the message?

Thank you so much if anyone knows how to solve it !!!

Comment: No, it is not possible to hide text in SMS messages or even delete some SMS messages in Android, unless your app is defined as the primary app for SMS handling

Comment: @Tim got any solution?